# Help to solve this integral :)

Tags: integration

$$ g(t) = A \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} h(\omega) f(t-\omega) d\omega$$

$$h(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} A & 0\leq t\leq {T\over2}\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.     $$

$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} A & {T\over2}\leq t\leq T \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.     $$

I didn't find a way to solve it :(, please help

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Obviously, we have $g(t)=A^{2}\int_{0}^{\tfrac{T}{2}}f(t-w) dw$ (why?). Now, you can continue with inserting the definition of $f$.

Comment: Or look for Heaviside function and convolution.

Comment: Alex exactly i've Stopped at what you say , but i'v no idea what to do by f(t-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given expression is the convolution between $h(t)$ and $f(t)$

$$
 g(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll} 0 & t\leq {T\over2}  \ \mbox{or}\  t\geq {3T\over2}\\
A^3\left(t-{T\over2}\right) & {T\over2}\leq t\leq {T}\\ 
A^3\left({3T\over2}-t\right) & {T}\leq t\leq {3T\over2} \end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: yes this is the right answer , but how did you work it ? a normal calculation ?

Comment: i've stopped at $$g(t) = A^2 \int_0^{T\over2} f(t-\omega)d\omega $$

Comment: @user160133  convolution is the interation of the product of the 2 function. consider $f(t-w)$ which is the reflection of $f(w)$ for t = 0. as t increases we shift the function to the right. Now the result is 0 whereever these 2 dont overlap. i.e. $t<T/2$ and $t>T/2$. for $T/2<t<T$ the integral is $A^2$ * integral over $T/2$ to $t$ because this is  the region where the the functions are overlapping. i.e. their product is non-zero. Similarly $T$ to $3T/2$. I hope I have made it clear now

Comment: Yes its clear, thanks :) , but i have a question could the normal calculation gives an answer , i said that $h(\omega)$ is 0 if $\omega$ is not at [0,T/2] so all the integral is 0 , and we have just to solve this : $ g(t) = A^2 \int_0^{T\over2} f(t-\omega)d\omega $ and here we can do something

Comment: @user160133  You are assuming the result to be a value. But here the result is a function in $t$. You have to evaluate the integral for each value of $t$. As you said, it is 0 when $t=0$ and there is no overlap between these two functions. But when $T/2<t<3T/3$ and you integrate over $\omega$ you can see that the product is not zero

Comment: Mmm so whenever the question wants a function depend on a variable as result i shouldn't try to reduce the integral as i did , Thank You ^_^

Comment: @user160133   Yes you are right. The answer contains $A^3$ instead of $A^2$. I've made the correction

Answer (score -1):

A correct result has already been given; the following just examines some of the calculations in detail.

The expression $f(t - \omega)$ in the integrand is non-zero precisely when
$$\frac T 2 \le t - \omega \le T.$$
Multiplying each part by $-1$ reverses the direction of the inequalities:
$$-T \le \omega - t \le -\frac T 2,$$
so
$$t - T \le \omega \le t - \frac T 2.$$

So this part of the integrand is non-zero just when $\omega$ is in the interval
$\left[t - T, t - \frac T 2\right].$
The other part of the integrand is non-zero when $\omega$ is in 
$\left[0, \frac T 2\right].$
The three cases arise from whether one interval overlaps the other on the left, on the right, or not at all.